# Expiring/busting Etag in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, etag

When doing HTTP caching in rails, once would use:
fresh_when etag: @user, public: true

The problem with that is that if you chance your html for the page, the cached page is no longer going to be valid. Therefor we need a way to invalidate the page/etag every time we change something.

One way to do that is to change RAILS_CACHE_ID every time you deploy as per
[Etag busting on deployment](http://ninjasandrobots.com/how-to-bust-your-rails-etag-cache-on-deployment%20Etag%20busting%20on%20deployment) .However doing that will results in all etags, for all the pages getting expired for every deployment.

I would rather have a solution where  I can expire individual tags, for individual pages.

I could generate my own etag with a version like this:
fresh_when etag: (@user.updated_at.to_s + "V1"), public: true

But this just doesn't feel like the "Rails way". Any more elegant solutions?

Answer (score 1):

[There's an update to this article](http://ninjasandrobots.com/rails-caching-a-problem-with-etags-and-a-solution) with a corresponding library so you can just set a version in config. See the README at https://github.com/n8/bust_rails_etags

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Capistrano, or a deployment strategy where the `Rails.root` value changes on each deployment, you can add this to your application controller:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  # This causes http request caching to expire when we deploy.
  # The app is deployed /mnt/code/releases/<timestamp>
  etag { $etag_cache_control_fragement ||= Rails.root.to_s.split("/").last }
```

Reference here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActionController/ConditionalGet/ClassMethods.html